# how to save pdf file from Firebase to document directory

Tags: swift, firebase, swiftui, firebase-storage

Hello I'm try to save a file test.pdf from firebase storage to the document directory of my app
but unfortunately not working.

here my content view with a button to run the task:

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase
import WebKit


struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        VStack {

            Button(action: {
               let storage = Storage.storage()
                let storageRef = storage.reference()
                let islandRef = storageRef.child("test.pdf")
                // Create local filesystem URL
                let localURL = URL(string: self.cartellaDocuments())!
                
                let downloadTask = islandRef.write(toFile: localURL) { (url, err) in
                    if err != nil {
                     debugPrint(" // Uh-oh, an error occurred!")
                    } else {
                        debugPrint("\(String(describing: url))")
                    }
                }
            }) {
                Text("esegui")
            }
        }
    }

    func cartellaDocuments() -> String {
        let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
        debugPrint(paths[0])
        return paths[0]
    }
    
       
}
```

my storage in firebase:

[image: Firebase Storage]

I have try to follow the google firebase instruction but Im getting a following warning:

- failed because it was passed an URL which has no scheme
  [image: warning]

how can I solve this issue.

thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
    let pdfView = PDFView()
    pdfView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.view.addSubview(pdfView)

    pdfView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    pdfView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    pdfView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
    pdfView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    

    if let document = PDFDocument(url: URL.init(string: "https://your storage download url")!) {
        pdfView.document = document
    }
```